how to resolve auth error in pusher alert
I have two projects backend and frontend. For both project I have different server. In this i need alert notification from backend to frontend using pusher for private channel.
I make one channel in pusher that is test_pusher.2 and in backend i create event and in frontend i add event listner. I mention below my code.I get error in frontend POST http://restaurant.test/broadcasting/auth 419 (unknown status)
*Backend Event Code
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcastNow;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class EventName implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        Log::info('Event created with data: ' . json_encode($data));
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        Log::info('Restaurant ID: ' . $this->data['restaurant_id']);
        return new PrivateChannel('test_pusher.' . $this->data['restaurant_id']);
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'test-push-event';
    }

    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return [
            'order_id' => $this->data['id'],
            'message' => 'New order received!',
            // Add more data as needed for the notification
        ];
    }
}

*Frontend Code
import Echo from '../../node_modules/laravel-echo/dist/echo.js';
// import Pusher from 'pusher-js';

console.log("test");

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'a1226f20b5b3deb64263',
    cluster: 'ap2',
    forceTLS: true,
    authEndpoint: 'http://restaurant.test/broadcasting/auth',    
});

window.Echo.private('test_pusher.2')
    .listen('.test-push-event', function(data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    });

